# Call the C Function using selector method and accessing self in the method of c in iPhone

Tags: iphone, c, ios5, selector

I am implemented some thing in C function and i want to call the another c method using NSTimer method but the selector not worked and also self method not called. How can do that?

```
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:900 target:self selector:@selector(prepareToUploadLog()) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

void prepareToUploadLog(void) is another function

Comment: @PaulR update the question with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a):

> **aSelector:** The message to send to target when the timer fires. The selector **must correspond to a method** that returns void and takes a single argument. The timer passes itself as the argument to this method.

So you can't use a C function and have to add an Objective C method that wraps the C function.

```
- (void)prepareToUpload
{
    prepareToUploadLog();
}
```